# Exprimer l'anteriorité avec le passé composé

Tags: grammaire, conjugaison, concordance-des-temps

On utilise le passé antérieur pour exprimer l'antériorité d'une action par rapport à une autre action au passé simple.

Par exemple,

> Quand il eut fini de parler, il partit.

Le passé simple est très rare à l'oral de nos jours, et il est naturel de le remplacer par un passé composé.

**Comment doit être changé le verbe au passé antérieur pour conserver l’antériorité ?**

Conserve-t-on le passé composé ou utilise-t-on un passé surcomposé ?

Laquelle des deux phrases suivantes est correcte ?

> Quand il a fini de parler, il est parti.

ou

> Quand il a eu fini de parler, il est parti.

Answer (score 4):

### Quand il a fini de parler, il est parti.

Dans cette phrase, le passé composé ne se comprend pas comme tel, mais plutôt comme une **forme <s>passive</s> active** du présent de l'indicatif où "*parti*" est un attribut du sujet. Cette nuance est difficile à voir car <s>le présent passif et le passé composé ont la même construction (seule différence : le verbe auxilliaire du passif est *toujours* le verbe *être*)</s> le participe passé est ici employé en tant qu'adjectif.
Concrètement, on ne ressent pas dans cette formulation le lien de cause à effet exprimé dans la phrase `Quand il eut fini de parler, il partit.`  Comme si le fait de partir et le fait de finir de parler étaient asynchrones : il peut avoir commencé à partir avant la fin du discours.
Le résultat de cette phrase peut sembler étrange, surtout connaissant ce qui est attendu, mais c'est le résultat que donne cette formulation.

Cette phrase n'est pas incorrecte, mais elle ne transmet pas l'information souhaitée.

### Quand il a eu fini de parler, il est parti.

Cette phrase par contre est une excellente reformulation de la phrase d'origine.

En effet, le passé composé `il a fini` est transformé en passé **surcomposé** `il a eu fini`. Cette différence est capitale pour deux raisons :

- Elle force la proposition `il est parti` à être compris au passé composé. Le <s>passif</s> présent est incorrect ici. Pour utiliser <s>du passif</s> l'adjectif, il eût fallu utiliser l'imparfait <s>passif</s> `était parti`.
- Elle traduit parfaitement l'antériorité du passé antérieur, en ce sens que la seconde action est la conséquence de l'accomplissement de la première. Plus clairement, la fait de partir est la suite directe du fait de finir de parler.

### Pour répondre à ta question :

> Quand il a eu fini de parler, il est parti.

C'est parfait.

Comment: Partir étant intransitif ("il part quelque chose" n'a aucun sens), je ne vois pas comment "être parti" pourrait être un passif...

Comment: Oui, tout juste. C'est un présent de l'indicatif où *parti* est un attribut du sujet. Je me suis laissé enporté par le fait que l'on peut "être parti" dans le sens où celà désigne un état de fait, et non une action. J'édite.

Answer (score 2):

L'utilisation d'un passé surcomposé est correcte, mais ce n'est pas la formulation la plus courante (et certains n'utilisent pas les temps surcomposés qui sont parfois considérés comme régionaux ou désuets).

Les formulations les plus courantes n'utiliseraient pas *quand*, mais *après* : *après avoir fini de parler, il est parti* ou *après qu'elle ait fini de parler, il est parti* (bien que considéré comme incorrect par les grammairiens qui refusent l'usage du subjonctif avec *après que* et demandent donc *après qu'elle a fini de parler, il est parti*; ils sont tellement peu suivis qu'on se fait parfois reprendre quand on le fait).